# Conflicting records when recording time taken to for regex to to find a match

Tags: c#, .net, regex, performance

**WHAT I WANTED:** I had to see and prove the outcome whether simple regex runned slower than compiled one or not. I decided to generate 100000 random strings, make two regex- one simple and one compiled- and check for a match in this 100000 set of strings. Also, to have many outputs to resolve from, what I did was initially I took all 100000 strings and ran the code and logged the timings, then I took first 80000 strings from the same set and logged the output, then I took first 50000 strings from the same set and logged the output and so on...

**THE CODE:**

```
var chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
var random = new Random();
int[] reps = new int[] { 1,10,100,1000,2000,5000,8000,10000,20000,50000,80000,100000 };

List<string> strings = new List<string>();
// generating random strings
for (int i = 0; i < reps[reps.Length-1]; i++)
     strings.Add(new string(
                    Enumerable.Repeat(chars, 8)
                              .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)])
                              .ToArray()));

String regexStr = "[AEIOU]{2,3}(QWERTY|ASDFGH|ZXCVBN){}";
Regex regexSimple = new Regex(regexStr);
Regex regexCompiled = new Regex(regexStr, RegexOptions.Compiled);

using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\harshittiwari\Desktop\Assignment1\test2.txt"))
{
       file.WriteLine("numberOfStrings,ticksForSimpleRegex,ticksForComplexRegex");

       List<long> simple = new List<long>();
       List<long> compiled = new List<long>();
       for (int j = reps.Length - 1; j >= 0; j--)
       {
             Stopwatch time1 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
             for (int k = 0; k < reps[j]; k++)
                  regexSimple.Matches(strings[k]);
             time1.Stop();
             simple.Add(time1.ElapsedTicks);
       }

       for (int j = reps.Length - 1; j >= 0; j--)
       {
                    Stopwatch time1 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                    for (int k = 0; k < reps[j]; k++)
                        regexCompiled.Matches(strings[k]);
                    time1.Stop();
                    compiled.Add(time1.ElapsedTicks);
       }

       for (int j = reps.Length - 1,k=0; j >= 0; j--,k++)
            file.WriteLine(reps[j] + "," + simple[k] + "," + compiled[k]);
}
```

**THE PROBLEM:** I get some weird output which is hard to explain. The output is:

```
numberOfStrings,ticksForSimpleRegex,ticksForComplexRegex
100000,300368,217506
80000,240373,201553
50000,178212,98878
20000,13362,202933
10000,6417,6377
8000,5868,7408
5000,3737,3142
2000,160473,1921
1000,1351,1883
100,84,141
10,23,21
1,17,17
```

Note that ticksForSimpleRegex for numberOfStrings=2000 is significantly greater than that for numberOfStrings=5000. Everytime I run the program it's more or less the same. Is it because of some caching problem or due to compiler optimization? Also, what should I do to make the output consistent? By consistent I mean ticksForSimpleRegex should be in decreasing order(basic logic: number of strings decreases, time taken shold decrease.)

Here I also wanted to say that, initially I was reading less number of strings and then going for more number of strings, like:

```
1,..,..
10,..,..
100,..,..
1000,..,..
...
80000,..,..
100000,..,..
```

However, I realized some caching issues and decided to go with the order it is there now.

**EDIT1:** I read http://allben.net/post/2009/08/06/Performance-Compiled-vs-Interpreted-Regular-Expressions They say taht interpreted(simple) regex should have taken less time, however in our case, this is not the result. Why is it so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the `IsMatch()` method instead of `Matches()`, the code does not create a large amount of objects that need to be collected (and probably are collected when you see the performance hits). I seem to be getting quite consistent results this way.

Comment: This seems to work in getting the consistent results. Still it does not explain the reason behind the output I am getting.

Comment: I edited my answer - I think all these objects are at some points collected by the Garbage Collector, and the time it takes to clean up is added to your measurements. You could try keeping your original code and force a `GC.Collect()` and see if that changes anything.

Comment: +1 for pointing out how to get the consistent result. Why is garbage collector doing it's job at 2000 or 1000 substrings. I am still not clear on that. Also, it would be great if you could give some insights on the edits.

Comment: I got my answer, as to why specifically garbage collector kicks in at 2000 or 1000 everytime. The reason being that the objects and size of objects remain the same, matches and regex, and heap size remains the same. That is the reason garbage collector gets filled up at that time only. If I change the size of random strings, then this may differ.

Comment: I wouldn't know the exact GC rules so I'm glad you figured that one out. I only reasoned why you got inconsistent results and found that only using `IsMatch` makes your script produce less dead objects. I'm afraid I can't help you with why compiled regexes are sometimes slower, that's a different question alltogether.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to C.Evenhuis answer
I got my answer, as to why specifically garbage collector kicks in at 2000 or 1000 everytime. The reason being that the objects and size of objects remain the same, matches and regex, and heap size remains the same. That is the reason garbage collector gets filled up at that time only. If I change the size of random strings, then this may differ.

Answer to EDIT1 is that in the mentioned benchmarking, 5000 different regex and benchmarking for compiled and interpreted ones. And we are using 1 regex. That being said, it is evident that if you have many number of regexes it is better to use interpreted regexes. If you have a simple regex and have to test it on many strings, use compiled regexes